# SQL Group By and Agregate a column and its correspondent value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

```
f1     f2     f3
----------------
10     20     30
10     15     50
11     12     25
11     79     13
```

Grouping by f1, how to get the max f2 and its correspondent f3?

```
f1     f2     f3
----------------
10     20     30
11     79     13
```

Comment: This is a[tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem, of which [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515354/optimal-performing-query-for-latest-record-for-each-n) is an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it this way

```
SELECT t1.f1
,      t.f2
,      t1.f3
FROM        tbl   t1

cross apply (SELECT max(f2) f2
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY f1) t
WHERE t1.f2=t.f2
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may use a cte with a row_number, partition by f1 and select only first row of each (ordered by f2 desc, which will give you the max f2)

```
with cte as (select 
              f1, 
              f2, 
              f3, 
              row_number() over(partition by f1 order by f2 desc) rn 
            from t) 
select 
   f1, 
   f2, 
   f3 
from cte
where rn = 1
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c196b/5)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by f1 order by f2 desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this one (without RN):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.f1,x.f2,x.f3
FROM  YourTable a
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 f2,f3 
             FROM YourTable b 
             WHERE a.f1 = b.f1 ORDER BY b.f2 DESC) x
```